# can't put variables inside sqlite3 query in flask

Tags: python, sqlite

```py
def query_db(query, args=(), one=False):
    cur = get_db().execute(query, args)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    cur.close()
    return (rv[0] if rv else None) if one else rv
```

Like documentation says, and I tried:

```py
query_db("INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (name, email, password))
```

it didn't work, and I tried:

```py
cur = get_db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (name, email, password))
```

also didn't work. How can I pass variables inside my request?

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly didn't work? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupid formatting of question, it was by mistake. The query just does not do anything

Comment: How do you see it does nothing? Also - are you commenting the cursor after executing the `insert` statement?

Comment: @Mureinik because it didn't add row inside table. And what means commenting cursor? You mean for telling what this query did? If so, I did not, just because I only trying to figure out how to do this, at this moment.

Comment: I think he means "are you **committing** the cursor?".

Comment: I already fixed cur = get_db.cursor() to cur = get_db().cursor(), and at this moment I understand that it's not variables. I tried cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass) VALUES ('namesdaf', 'adsf', 'asdf')") and it did not add new row

Comment: Did you do `get_db.commit()` after the insert?

Comment: Indeed, **committing**. Damn grammerly auto-correct :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The insertion looks correct. However, until you perform a commit, any DML operation (like an `insert`) would only be visible from the session that performed it, and will implicitly be rolled back when the connection is terminated.

To make a long story short - call `commit`:

```py
cur = get_db.cursor()
cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, email, pass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", (name, email, password))
get_db.commit() # Here!
```

Comment: THANK YOU, it worked for me. But I still want to make my queries using function, because I need to make them a lot of times. Do you have any ideas where should I put get_db.commit() inside my query_db()?

Comment: @Anatoliy after you `execute` the query.

Comment: thanks, now it works. I spent 4 hours trying to figure out it by myself..